# Linked list error: trying to access something that is 'NULL' or uninitialized

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on a c++ header program where I am required to create a linked list and run it through a gitlab tester after its been programed to test if it's been coded correctly. So I have my code written and it runs just fine in VS and Xcode, when I test it in gitlab it fails. What I'm being told is that

"Your code is accessing some memory that is NULL. Since this is in the function where you are removing nodes, you are doing something wrong in the remove single node function or the remove sections of nodes function. You could be deleting nodes before you advance your pointer to the next node, meaning that you deallocate memory of a node, but you didn't keep track of the node's next pointer, so when you try to advance the pointer or are trying to edit where nodes point you are accessing memory you shouldn't."

" With memory access error it is usually when you are trying to access something that does not exist. A common mistake that students have is in the insert function when you are trying to insert to the back of the list you should have and if statement that checks for that since the set up for insert involves going to the node after and if you are inserting at the end a memory access violation occurs"

Here is a link with the program requirements if needed to reference as well as the code I written, I'll include it here as well. But I can't see where I am making a mistake and how to fix it, if anyone could help it would be really helpful.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y4wFdhfl7Rhm3utLKQVrGH9xful819N-zlB-cTJARJw/edit?usp=sharing

List.hpp Code:

```
#ifndef ECE275LIB_CONTAINERS_LIST_H
#define ECE275LIB_CONTAINERS_LIST_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace  ECE275Lib { namespace containers{
template <class type_name> class Node{
public:
    Node<type_name> *next;
    type_name data;
};

template <class type_name> class List{
public:
    Node<type_name> *head=new Node<type_name>;
    
    List(){
        head=NULL;
    }
    List(unsigned int N){
        head=NULL;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
            push_back();
        }
    }
    
    void remove(type_name i){
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        temp=head;
        Node<type_name> *temp2=new Node<type_name>;
        if(temp->data==i){
            head=temp->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        else{
            while(1){
                if(temp->next->data==i && temp->next->next==NULL){
                    temp2=temp->next;
                    delete temp2;
                    temp->next=NULL;
                    break;
                }
                
                else if(temp->next->data==i){
                    temp2=temp->next;
                    temp->next=temp2->next;
                    delete temp2;
                    break;
                }
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void remove(Node<type_name> *node){
        Node<type_name> *temp;
        Node<type_name> *prev;
        temp=head;
        if(node==head){
            head=temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return ;
        }
        prev=head;
        while(1){
            temp=prev->next;
            if(node==temp){
                prev->next=temp->next;
                delete temp;
                break;
            }
            prev=prev->next;
        }
    }
    
    void remove(unsigned int s, unsigned int e){
        unsigned int i=0;
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *nex=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *curr=new Node<type_name>;
        temp=head;
        while(1){
            if(i==s){
                curr=temp;
                nex=temp->next;
                for(unsigned int j=i;j<=e;j++){
                    remove(curr);
                    curr=nex;
                    nex=nex->next;
                }
                break;
                
            }
            i++;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    
    void display(){
        
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        temp=head;
        while(1){
            cout<<temp->data<<"\t";
            if(temp->next==NULL){
                break;
            }
            else{
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void push_front(type_name d){
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        if(head==NULL){
            temp->data=d;
            temp->next=NULL;
            head=temp;
        }
        else{
            temp->data=d;
            temp->next=head->next;
            head=temp;
        }
    }
    
    void push_back(type_name d){
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *curr=new Node<type_name>;
        
        if(head==NULL){
            temp->data=d;
            temp->next=NULL;
            head=temp;
        }
        else{
            temp->data=d;
            temp->next=NULL;
            curr=head;
            while(1){
                if(curr->next==NULL){
                    curr->next=temp;
                    break;
                }
                curr=curr->next;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    void insert(unsigned int index,type_name value){
        unsigned int i=0;
        
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *temp2=new Node<type_name>;
        temp=head;
        if(index==0){
            push_front(value);
            
            return ;
        }
        while(1){
            if(i==index-1){
                temp2->data=value;
                temp2->next=temp->next;
                temp->next=temp2;
                break;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            if(temp->next==NULL && index==i+2){
                Node<type_name> *temp3=new Node<type_name>;
                temp3->data=value;
                temp3->next=NULL;
                temp->next=temp3;
                break;
            }
            else if(temp->next==NULL){
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        
    }
    
    void push_back(){    // for empty initialization
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *curr=new Node<type_name>;
        
        if(head==NULL){
            temp->next=NULL;
            head=temp;
        }
        else{
            temp->next=NULL;
            curr=head;
            while(1){
                if(curr->next==NULL){
                    curr->next=temp;
                    break;
                }
                curr=curr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    Node<type_name>* front(){
        return head;
    }
    
    Node<type_name>* back(){
        Node<type_name> *temp;
        temp=head;
        while(1){
            if(temp->next==NULL){
                return temp;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    
    type_name at(unsigned int i){
        unsigned int j=0;
        Node<type_name> *temp;
        temp=head;
        while(1){
            if(j==i){
                return temp->data;
            }
            j++;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    
    void assign(unsigned int i, type_name d){
        unsigned int j=0;
        Node<type_name> *temp;
        temp=head;
        while(1){
            if(j==i){
                temp->data=d;
                break;
            }
            j++;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    
    unsigned int size(){
        unsigned int i=0;
        Node<type_name> *temp;
        temp=head;
        if(head==NULL){
            return 0;
        }
        while(1){
            if(temp->next==NULL){
                return i+1;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    void insert(unsigned int i,List<type_name> &other){
        unsigned int j=0;
        Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *restore_point=new Node<type_name>;
        Node<type_name> *nodeOfOther=new Node<type_name>;
        temp=head;
        while(1){
            if(j==i-1){
                restore_point=temp->next;
                nodeOfOther=other.front();
                temp->next=nodeOfOther;
                other.back()->next=restore_point;
                break;
                
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            j++;
        }
    }
    
};
} }
using namespace ECE275Lib::containers;


#endif
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` instead of C's typeless `NULL`. Also don't forget about `auto` which can make your life way easier.

Comment: There is a whole ton of code to review here, and on first glance, *way* more than a typical linked list needs. Why does `remove()` involve any allocation? There's a bunch of things created and seemingly arbitrarily deleted at times.

Comment: It would be nice if your variable names actually communicated something, and where that wasn't enough, that you had a comment or two. This code is far from self-explanatory.

Comment: Hello memory leak: `Node<type_name> *temp=new Node<type_name>; temp=head;` Three more in `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really "debug my code" and is probably better asked on a code-review site, rather than here, which is for specific, focused questions.

But I'll give you a few suggestions anyway, focusing mainly on *remove* logic.  As you're not here for praise on what works, I'll only look for and point out errors and it will sound negative (sorry) but it is intended to be helpful.

1. *Never* `using namespace std` in headers (or any other namespace, for that matter).  It pollutes the global namespace of anyone who includes your header, and they cannot opt out of it without opting out of all your code.

2A) It looks like you're calling "new" in a lot of places just hoping to clear up a null pointer, without understanding why you're hitting one.  Plastering code with wishful thinking is only going to make your code worse, and if you're REALLY unlucky it'll hide the bug symptoms, but you'll never quite know if it's fixed (but it's probably not.)  Take time to understand where the real problem is.

2B) For this code, there should be *at most* one call to `new` at the point where you want to add a new node to the list.  Nowhere else.  And if you use smart pointers and make_unique, you could get that down to zero.

3. remove() should never allocate.  Never.  See 2 above.
4. what should happen if I call remove(3) and your list is empty?  Ans: inside the first `if` condition of remove(), temp will be null and you will dereference it.
5. you read temp->next without checking if it's null in several places.
6. reading temp->next->next should always be a red flag for bugs.  Even if it's valid (probably isn't) it should be avoided whenever possible.  In a linked list, you're generally always off-course if you ever need to look ahead that far (if at all).  You just don't know where the next null is.  Also, you're in a loop, remember you can save some work to the next iteration rather than trying to handle multiple cases in one iteration.

6b) For a linked list, looking head is generally not a good approach.  It's better to stay on the current node and keep track of where you've been (in prev).  Don't or worry about where you're going--the next iteration will handle that.  If you are on the node that needs to be removed, remove it, fixup prev's next to current's next and remove current.

7. when you can, initialize your variables as you declare them.  Don't declare pointers and leave them uninitialized, and then assign to them the next line.  It helps avoid future mistakes where you read from the variable before it's assigned.
8. Don't repeat yourself like this:

   if (temp->next->data==i && ...)
   ...
   else if (temp->next->data==i)
   ...

You end up with repetition at worst, but can introduce bugs and missed opportunities.

9. if I ask to remove() a value, I'd like to know if it was actually removed or not.  A return value for success or failure makes a better interface.
10. `temp` is a truly awful name for variables, because instead of giving the meaning of what the data is, it gives a vague description of the lifetime of the variable referring to that data.  When I was in school, code would not be accepted if we did not use meaningful names, and "Avoid the TEMPtation" was one of the commandments.  In hindsignt, it is still good advice.  Here, *temp* should be "cur_node" or something meaningful like that.

Good luck.